# Could I program my own application firmware on a certified BLE module?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I want to send some data which I get from a sensor with I2C over Bluetooth LE.

Is it possible to bring my own application which reads the sensor data together with the BLE stack onto the certified BLE module, or do I always need a microcontroller which communicates with the BLE module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally a commercial, fully certified BLE module will not have the stack accessible to third parties. You would have to have a way to acess the module via a UART interface or similar, so that you can configure the BLE module via ASCII commands. Second, you will need to send to the module, via the same comms channel, the sensor data that you obtain. So usually you will require some form of u-controller or an FPGA or similar to do this with.

Having said that, there are other Bluetooth modules with analogue audio capabilities that can be preconfigured to stream audio to/from the module to an external head-set or speaker etc. without needing a mico-controller. This presumes that you can pre-configure and pair your module with your other audio device so that it can begin streaming as soon as you have the paired device active.

In your case you are dealing with some digital sensor data obtained via I2C, and you will need to obtain this and also send this data to a BLE module etc. So you can see that a small microcontroller will be required to interface your sensor via I2C, to also configure the BLE module, and then also send the data to the BLE module every 30 seconds or whatever you require.

You may be lucky to find a BLE module with an A/D interface that you can preprogram to read your sensor with an analogue interface and not have to use a microcontroller. Otherwise you may find a BLE module with an integrated mcirocontroller that is made accessible for programming directly, but the BLE stack will still not be accessible.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, there are BLE modules that need to be controlled via a separate uC (perhaps via AT commands or other). The HC-05 comes to mind.

But there are also modules that have their own incorporated uC in it.

I have experience with the nRF52832 chip from Nordic, that also has several pre-certified modules sold in the market. It also has its uC with different peripheral as most uCs in the market. You can add your own custom firmware on top of the BLE stack.

Now, learning how to do so it's another story, but there are resources online to learn.

Answer (score 1):

u-blox has a [range of modules](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product-selector?product_technology=Bluetooth%2520low%2520energy&product_class=Module) that can be programmed to run custom firmware. The typical modules that are controlled by a separate microcontroller run the [u-connectXpress](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/u-connectxpress) software. open CPU modules are the ones that are made to run custom firmware.

For example: [NORA-B1](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/nora-b1-series-open-cpu)

You can even buy an [evaluation kit](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/mini-nora-b1).

[image]